# Navicat (MySQL) Character Encoding Error

Tags: mysql, insert, navicat

I am using Navicat 11.0.8 and I am trying to insert values into a table using a query but when i try to insert the values with the query it works but the character encoding is messed up!

As you can see on my code, the table is 'table' and i am inserting an ID, VNUM and a NAME. The VNUM is '体字' and the NAME is 'Versão'.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('1', '体字', 'Versão');
```

Instead of showing '体字' on the VNUM and 'Versão' on the NAME, it shows 'ä½“å­—' and 'VersÃ£o'.

This is very bad for me because I am trying to insert more than 5000 lines with alot of information.

I have tried to set the Character Encoding of the table using this these commands:

```
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
&    
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET big5 COLLATE big5_chinese_ci;
&
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I also have tried to delete my table and create a new one with the character encoding already to utf-8 and send the values..

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
CREATE TABLE `table` (
`vnum` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`name` varbinary(200) NOT NULL default 'Noname',
`locale_name` varbinary(24) NOT NULL default 'Noname',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=big5_chinese_ci;

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('1', '体字', 'Versão');
```

Still show's 'ä½“å­—' and 'VersÃ£o'.

If i edit the table manually, it show's correct! But i am not going to edit 5000+ lines...

Comment: Are you using proper encoding for your connection?

Comment: Yes, I tryed to change the query and i changed 'Versão' to a hexadecimal code and it worked. But for the chinese character no work. Shows ?? INSERT INTO table VALUES ('1', 0x3f3f, 0x56657273e36f);

Answer (score 1):

`it shows 'ä½“å­—' and 'VersÃ£o'.` -- Sounds like you had `SET NAMES latin1`.  Do

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

after connecting and before INSERTing.  That tells mysqld what encoding the client is using.

Verify the data stored by doing `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`  The utf8 (or utf8mb4) hex for `体字` is `E4BD93E5AD97`.  Interpreting those *same* bytes as `latin1` gives you `ä½“å­—`;

utf8 can handle those, plus `ã`; I don't know if big5 can.

Actually, I suggest you use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  This is in case you encounter some of the 4-byte Chinese characters.

If you still have latin1 columns that need changing to utf8mb4, [see my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter), which discusses the "2-step ALTER", but using `BINARY` or `BLOB` (not big5) as the intermediate.